# API amoCRM Python ошибка валидации данных

Tags: python, requests

Работаю с API amoCRM. Требуется добавить пользователя через API.
Но при отправке запроса получаю ошибку:

```
{'detail': 'Request validation failed',
 'status': 400,
 'title': 'Bad Request',
 'type': 'https://httpstatus.es/400',
 'validation-errors': [{'errors': [{'code': 'InvalidType',
                                    'detail': 'This value should be of type '
                                              'array.',
                                    'path': 'first_name'},
                                   {'code': 'InvalidType',
                                    'detail': 'This value should be of type '
                                              'array.',
                                    'path': 'last_name'},
                                   {'code': 'InvalidType',
                                    'detail': 'This value should be of type '
                                              'array.',
                                    'path': 'custom_fields_values'}],
                        'request_id': '0'}]}
```

Сам код:

```
def check_user(request):
    full_name = request.GET['user_name']
    first_name = full_name.split()[0]
    last_name = full_name.split()[1]
    mail = request.GET['user_mail'],
    data = {
        "first_name": first_name,
        "last_name": last_name,
        "custom_fields_values": [
            {
                "field_id": 640613,
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": mail
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}'}
    response = requests.post(
        url=f'https://{SUBDOMAIN}.amocrm.ru/api/v4/contacts',
        data=data,
        headers=headers).json()
    pprint(response)
```

Comment: Кажется вы не правильно передаете data в параметры запросы

Comment: Попробуйте передавать через json=data вместо data=data, тогда ваш словарь с параметрами автоматически кодируется в json

Comment: Или же  data=json.dumps(data), в любой случае сейчас вы передаете словарь питона, а надо передавать json

Comment: @Vasily похоже на то, потому что сейчас попробовал в postman все сработало. Попробую передать как json

Comment: @Vasily Спасибо. Все таки проблема была в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать через json=data вместо data=data, тогда ваш словарь с параметрами автоматически кодируется в json